# How to upload image file only in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

I am having this little problem and i dont know what it is?

```
<div class="add-picture">
   <vs-upload limit="1" action="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/" @on-success="successUpload" />
</div>
```

I dont know what javascript does to do this.

Comment: If you are using a third-party component, generally it has implemented the features of uploading files internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue itself doesn't have the ability upload the file to your server. You can pass parameters from Vue into a POST request to a back end using [method event handlers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) and a client like [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios), but Vue itself merely forwards the data while something like Axios would be responsible for the transfer.

There are other clients out there who can handle HTTP requests and a plethora of components out there for handling file uploads, but Axios is the one I chose as an example.

This article [here](https://serversideup.net/uploading-files-vuejs-axios/) might be of more assistance.

Answer (score -1):

```
<template>
  <vs-upload limit=1 action="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/" @on-success="successUpload" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods:{
    successUpload(){
      console.log('success')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

limit takes a Number not a String. Vue is terribly confusing on this subject, I know.
And Vuesax library is full of bugs, fyi.
https://lusaxweb.github.io/vuesax/components/upload.html#automatic